# Fetched value is undefined jquery (traversal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, traversal

Actually am using Jqgrid but in browser console html look like this

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>
     <input type="text" id="priority_1per" value='10'>hello <input>
</td>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="priority_2per" value='20'>hellob <input>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

there is a column: "priority1" "priority2" which has textbox

```
 $('body').on('change', '#priority_1per', function () {
        //debugger;
        var priority1 = $(this).val();
        var priority2 = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").find("input[type=text]").find("#priority_2per")

        alert(priority1)
        alert(priority2)
        console.log(priority2)
    });
```

=>var priority1 am getting value (this).val()
=> but am not getting value of priority2 column data (i dono am doing crrt traversing or not)

```
jQuery.fn.init [prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(10)]
length: 0
prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(10) [input#productpriority.form-control.productpriority, input#divisionname.form-control._division.ui-autocomplete-input, input#categoryname.form-control.category.ui-autocomplete-input, input#subcategoryname.form-control.subcategory.ui-autocomplete-input, input#priority_1.form-control.plantname.plantCode1, input#priority_1per.form-control.priority_1per.number, input#priority_2.form-control.plantname.plantCode2, input#priority_2per.form-control.priority_2per.number, input#priority_3.form-control.plantname.plantCode3, input#priority_3per.form-control.priority_3per.number, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(12)]
[[Prototype]]: Object(0)
```

this is the error am finding (not an error but mistake in travesal)

PLEASE help me out
[html look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDFJN.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to your `find()` logic. You use the first `find()` to get both the `input type="text"` elements, then the second is trying to find a **child** `#priority_2per` element inside the first `input`. This clearly cannot be found as it's not valid HTML.

To fix the problem remove the first `find()` and add `val()`:

```
var priority2 = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").find("#priority_2per").val()
```

***However*** as the elements have `id` attributes on them, and `id` *have* to be unique in the DOM, then the traversal logic is entirely redundant. You can just select by the `id` directly.

In addition, your HTML is invalid. `<input />` elements have no closing tag. Here's a full working example:

```js
$('body').on('change', '#priority_1per', function() {
  var priority1 = $(this).val();
  var priority2 = $("#priority_2per").val();

  console.log(priority1);
  console.log(priority2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="priority_1per" value="10" />hello
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="priority_2per" value="20" />hellob
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: tq. ur explanation was good and i got to know my mistake. tq for helping me out